# SQL2542N - No match for a database image file was found based on the source database alias

Tags: linux, db2

I'm trying to restore a DB from a Linux system to a Windows. I'm working with DB2 9.7.7. I want to create a new DB with the restored DB.
The DB file has this name: `DBBACKUP.0.db2inst1.DBPART000.20140614125950.001` and I've the file under `/home/db2inst1` folder. So, logged as DB2 administrator (db2inst1), I'm trying with this command:

> db2inst1@machine:/data/home/db2inst1> db2 restore db DBBACKUP

or

> db2inst1@machine:/data/home/db2inst1> db2 restore db DBBACKUP taken at 20140614125950

and it returns me:

> SQL2542N  No match for a database image file was found based on the source database alias "DBBACKUP" and timestamp "" provided.

It can not find the database, but I don't know if the error is the name of the DB I put in the command, or the path is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: You're missing the `FROM` clause in your `RESTORE` command.

Comment: Also, is your database really called "DBBACKUP"?

Comment: What does `db2ckrst -d DBBACKUP -t 20140614125950` say?

Comment: Does it matter that you are running the command from the `/data/home/db2inst1` directory while the file you say is located in `/home/db2inst1`?

Comment: @Lennart Based on the file name the backup image is a full backup; however it's possible that someone renamed the file, so it might be worthwhile to do `db2ckbkp -H DBBACKUP.0.db2inst1.DBPART000.20140614125950.001` and see what proper name of the file should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers.

Finally I asked the guy who had give me the copy of the database. It came from a Linux, and I was trying to restore in a Windows, so I think this was the main problem. I tried to do the restore on a Linux-Suse, and it worked.

Once more, it is good to start with the most obvious... sorry, and thanks!